Google Sheets variable dropdown menu
I want to create several dropdown menus that pull data from a table that contains an list of items and their category identifier. I looks like this :
Google sheets screenshot
In the first dropdown menu I want all the items that are in Category 1 and in the second drop down all the items that are in category 2.
Is there any way to accomplish this?
Best regards,
I tried ChatGPT solution and youtube videos but it seems that feature has recently been changed in google sheets.

There is this interesting article which explains how to create dependent drop downs, maybe it could help you:
[https://www.howtogeek.com/780950/how-to-create-a-dependent-drop-down-list-in-google-sheets/]
